# Save Blob to FileSystem in React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to download a PDF and share it via the 'expo-sharing' SDK. I can't use `FileSystem.createDownloadResumable` because the document is available via a POST request.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Download it as a `blob` and use `FileReader` to convert it to a base64 string to pass to `FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync`

```
const response = await axios.post(URL_PDF_CONTENT, { Benefits: payload }, { responseType: 'blob' });

const fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = async () => {
  const fileUri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}/pdf.pdf`;
  await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, fr.result.split(',')[1], { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });
  Sharing.shareAsync(fileUri);
};
fr.readAsDataURL(response.data);
```

Comment: After probably 6 hours solid trial and error, can confirm this is THE ONLY solution that currently works for an Expo managed project that acquires PDF via POST method. Fetch won't work, and FileSystem asyncDownload only supports GET requests (not POST), and rn-fetch-blob is not compatible with Expo. Thanks for this!